# Find difference in file encoding

Tags: bash, encoding, echo

I am sending email from the cmd with msmtp for that I do

```
cat > test1 << EOF
>From: "Tester"
>test
>EOF


cat test1 | msmtp email@mail.com
```

This works while:

```
echo -e 'From: "Tester"\ntest' > test2
cat test2 | msmtp email@mail.com
```

Doesn't work although

```
diff test1 test2
```

returned nothing and both

```
 file -bi test1 test2
```

returned the same results

```
 message/rfc822; charset=us-ascii
```

Comment: the new line \n isn't interprete with single quote

Comment: This has nothing to do with encoding and the diff should be returning something since the first cat would yield a two-line file while the echo command will only result in a one-liner. Either you've done something wrong or there is something you're not telling us.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you're not using the `-e` option with your echo command.

Try this:

```
echo -e 'From: "Tester"\ntest' > test2
cat test2 | msmtp email@mail.com
```

`-e` is for telling echo to interpret escaped chars (like "\n").

Comment: Ah sorry, I did have "-e" in my script, just did not posted it in the question.